# Windows 7 add network printer with .vbs scrpits

Tags: windows, printing

I want to add a network printer with the vbs scripts from the directory C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts.

The first line works:

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\de-DE\prnport.vbs -a -r IP_192.168.55.110 -h 192.168.55.110 -o raw -n 9100
```

but the next line:

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\de-DE\prndrvr.vbs -a -m "Xerox GPD PCL6 V4.1.585.13.0" -i  .\driver\x3UNIVX.inf -h .\driver
```

throws an error:
Cannot add printer. Xerox GPD PCL6 V4.1.585.13.0. Win32-Errorcode 87.

What do I wrong?
Is there a better solution do add a printer and install the driver with cmd or VB scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path must be in quotes and you need double backslashs.

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\de-DE\prndrvr.vbs -a -m "Xerox GPD PCL6 V4.1.585.13.0" -i  "driver'\x3UNIVX.inf" -h "driver\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\de-DE\prndrvr.vbs -a -m "Xerox GPD PCL6 V4.1.585.13.0" -h .\driver

skip the "-i <.inf file>"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).